# Hadoop install and Cloudera manager - SSH

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

Sorry, this is my second post in a matter of hours on the same topic. Just trying to get Hadoop installed using Cloudera's free install. I'm new to Linux and Hadoop.
Got to the point where I can log in to Cloudera Manager. Being the first log on, it prompts to create a cluster. Not sure what I'm supposed to put here, but localhost seems to be recognized and I can proceed. I accepted all the defaults on the Select Repository screen. Then I get to the SSH credentials screen.
Here I have no idea what I'm supposed to enter.
Should I leave root as user? And what is the password supposed to be then?
Or should I use my account? Can someone walk me through the parameters to choose on this screen?
All the combinations I try result in either an "authentication failure".

Thanks!

---

Adding a screen shot of the input screen and output screen. In the output if I click on details is says "exhausted authentication methods".

[image: the input screen]

[image: the authentication error, if I click on details is says "exhausted authentication methods"]

Comment: What OS are you installing this on version and all? Which CDH distribution are you installing (assume CDH4) but you should tell us? Could you provide the output at the screen where your confusion lies; the more you provide about your process the more we can help.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with CDH4. See the screen shots I added to my original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks based on the messages above that you are installing cloudera on a cluster. Is this your intention? Do you have a cluster (several computers) to install this in?

It is asking you for SSH access to your computer nodes so that it can go through them and install all the necessary packages so that you can have a working installation. It sounds like you are pretty new at this and you perhaps want to learn this technology and experiment with it.

May I suggest that you try one of the following sources instead?

This is a great first time tutorial to get a single node cluster going. It walks you through step by step and even shows you how to get the word count program running so that you can get a feel for what the logs look like and how to run programs. I've walked through this one and I recommend it. He also has a multi-node cluster tutorial that you can walk through after this one.

- http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

You can also walk through this tutorial from IBM that uses a Cloudera Virtual Machine to teach you about the Hadoop Infrastructure. This may be more in line with something you want since you were attempting to install Cloudera above and it teaches more about the Hadoop infrastructure than the toot above.

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1209hadoopbigdata/

Comment: Thanks. I had actually attempted the first tutorial a month ago and got stuck somewhere in the middle. I really liked the second link. Great article!

Comment: If you wanted to attempt it again you may be able to complete it by posting when you get stuck. It took me about three full hours to install it and research the log output and understand what was doing what but I came out enlightened with what to look for when I later installed cloudera's packages.

Comment: If I were to follow Michael Noll's tutorial, would I ever be able to get to a GUI type of solution like Cloudera or Horton VM's? At this point my focus is on practicing Pig, Hive and Mapreduce in a "as friendly as possible" environment. In that sense I like the GUIs provided by the VM's.

Comment: By the way, would it be appropriate to ask Hadoop non technical questions on this forum? I'm interested in opinions on training options, and would also like to get a better understanding of how Hadoop is being used by Data Scientists in places like Amazon, Facebook, Google... if I look at what mix of skills these companies look for when hiring data analysts, it's a mix of scripting languages, hadoop, R/SAS... what is the typical flow of a piece of analytics where you would use those type of skills?

Comment: If you are looking to increase your skills in the the Hadoop family vs installing Hadoop then I would suggest you walk through the IBM tutorial above. The VM contains what you are looking for preinstalled (Hive, PIG etc)

Comment: Some Non-technical are OK, but to make sure take a browse at some that have been asked previously it has been my experience that they get closed as off-topic or downvoted depending how it is asked. Read the how to ask questions part of the forum to be well versed in asking the type of question you want. Not sure what a typical flow is but the way my company uses data analyst is to build models to assess credit risk on individuals using everything from college report cards to bankruptcy. Each customer gets a model according to their risk assessment use case i.e. loan vs job vs etc.